# Need help naming this platform in my back yard

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

What do I call a semi-circular concrete platform in my back yard that looks like a stage. It is about 30 inches above my grass lawn and is attached to my rear wall and appears that it could be a band stage.
We currently use this as a conversation/fire pit area and it is always difficult to describe to someone who has not seen it. Photo attached:
[image: Back Yard Conversation/Fire Pit Area]

Comment: Of related interest: *[“Balconies”, “porches”, “decks”, “terraces”, “verandas”, “lanais”, “galleries”, and “piazzas” in GAE and dialectal AE](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/155973)*

Comment: Technically, it's a podium (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Podium) but if you say that, particularly in the US, people other than architects will think you mean a lectern.

Comment: "Hardscaped raised firepit"

Comment: Drone landing pad?

Answer (score 2):

It is a ***raised patio***

See [Images for raised patio](https://www.google.com/search?q=raised+patio&biw=1102&bih=569&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjcj77b8YnMAhUIYyYKHRsPCHsQsAQIGw)

I didn't find anything as definitive architecturally as the Oxford Dictionary is for words, but **raised patio** seems to be a common term.  There are many entries;  I picked this one at random:   [How to Build a Raised Patio](http://www.allanblock.com/retaining-walls/raised-patio.aspx)

Yours is beautiful.

Comment: How about a "deck" or a "stone deck"? You could also have some fun and call it an "altar,"which is a raised place or structure where sacrifices are offered and religious rites performed.

Answer (score 1):

I reckon I'd ask my guests to join me on ***the bandstand***.

Although, clearly, it cannot be a functioning bandstand as currently furnished, the OP says that *"it could be a band stage*", and it *is* a sociable location ("*a conversation/fire pit area*").

A fun, whimsical name, such as ***the bandstand*** seems more appropriate to the OP's request than anything more architecturally accurate.

Comment: Hi Dan, someone flagged your answer as being low-quality, possibly because it's too short or not detailed enough. I would recommend linking to a reputable dictionary definition of bandstand and pasting the definition into a blockquote, explaining why this is an appropriate name for the platform. - [From Review](http://english.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/174793)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a ***[dais](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dais)*** :

> - a raised platform in a large room or hall that people stand on when performing or speaking to an audience.

(M-W)